# How to break a while loop when I input via scanning nextline

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want to input something via scanning next line in a loop and at some conditions break the loop. But I found I can't break out and still in this loop.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        int count=1;
        while (true){
            line=scan.nextLine();
            if (line.equals(" ")){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(count);
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
}
```

What is expected is like this:

```
apple
soda
```

and then a space line

And the output would be:

```
apple
1
soda
2
```

and break out and end the program

But the actual is the loop continues until I end the terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: it should break if `equals` is used instead of `==` and user types blank character

Comment: @ValentinCarnu So what you mean is I need to let the line equals to a specific string when breaking the loop?

Comment: You need to check the user input using `equals`. For the code in the description the user needs to type blank character followed by enter to stop the app

Comment: @ValentinCarnu OK buddy, I fixed this. It's a tricky problem. What I write in code is line.equals(" ") and what I input is just nothing and Enter. This is the point. The solution is that I need to input " " and Enter... It is really tricky!

Comment: So you should change your condition to `if (line.trim().isEmpty())` and it will match if the line is either whitespace or completely empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` should work but if not, you can try something like this:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
int count=1;
boolean docontinue = true;
while (docontinue){
    line=scan.nextLine();
    if (line.equals(" ")){
        docontinue = false;
        System.out.println("break");
    }
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println(count);
    count=count+1;
}
```

If the break print is not working, it's because the if statement is not working too.

- If you enter a white space before pressing enter, you should compare the line to `" "`.
- If you only press enter to end the loop, you should compare the line
  to the empty string `""`. Indeed, [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) return the line
  without EOL char. So if you press enter, the line is empty with an
  EOL char.

Best

Comment: Thank you buddy. I have fixed this. What I write in code is line.equals(" ") and what I input is just nothing and Enter. This is the point. The solution is that I need to input " " and Enter... It is really tricky!

Comment: Yep ! That's what I explained in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equals` method to compare your string with `empty space`

```
if (line.equals(" ")){
    break;
}
```